# Big Query HTML interface not working on Ubuntu

Tags: google-chrome, google-bigquery

I have been using the Big Query browser interface on Chrome on my Ubuntu 10.04 machine for a couple of years.  Within the last couple of weeks the https://bigquery.cloud.google.com page would no longer load fully.  I get a mostly blank screen with only the "COMPOSE QUERY" button and links to Query History and Job History, but no datasets or tables are visible.  I am able to load the browser interface fine on my Windows 7 professional machine. The version of Chrome on the Ubuntu machine is 27.0.1453.93.  I know this is an old version of Chrome, but updates are no longer available on my version of Ubuntu.

Here is a screenshot of what I see on Ubuntu....
[image]

Comment: You should post as a bug, or try if you don't have adblocks. You can also find portable versions of some browsers

Answer (score 0):

That's an unsupported version of Chrome (or more likely -- Chromium, if it was installed from the standard repositories).

You should be able to install a more recent version from the following link, although I'm not certain that support goes back to 10.4:
https://www.google.com/chrome/browser/desktop/

I'd also strongly encourage you to upgrade to a more recent version of Ubuntu -- 10.4 LTS hit end-of-life earlier this year and I don't believe it is receiving any further security updates.

See:
http://www.ubuntu.com/info/release-end-of-life